# Solr 6 synonym relevancy score

Tags: solr, solr6, solr-schema

I have been experimenting with synonyms in solr 6. The stuff I have read before starting pointed out some differences in query time and index time synonyms. The main difference is IDF values while incorporating synonyms at index time and query time. In my experiment, I have found no difference in relevancy calculations in both the modes. The term frequency and the IDF values in index time and query time synonyms remains the same. I am using solr SynonymGraphFilterFactory and I am not using multi term synonyms. I want to know how is IDF value calculation for a term in both these modes is different?

Comment: you want to know difference b/w index and query time synonym work flow?

Comment: Thank u @CodeMagic. I have edited my question to be more explicit.